# How do I solve the following equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have the following problem:

\begin{align}
Y &= A X \\
Y &= R \exp \left(j \Phi\right) \text{element-wise}\\
X, R, \Phi &\in \Bbb R \\
A, Y &\in \Bbb C
\end{align}

I know what A is, I know what R is and I'm looking for X.

Basically, X is real, and Y is complex but I only know it's absolute value.

Is there an easy way to compute an answer?

I've thought of trying to cast this as some sort of optimisation problem, as ultimately I'm interested in finding the solutions numerically.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I don't know how relevant this might be but inverting A is trivial in my case.

**EDIT2**

Sorry about this but forgot to write that this is a matrix equation ie:

A is a matrix, X, Y, R, $\Phi$ are vectors.

**POTENTIAL ANSWER**

Not sure whether I should post this here or as an answer. I ended up posting it as part of the question as I'm no sure if it is correct has other problems.

I tried to pose this as an optimisation problem. I'm going to try and implement it and see but would love to get feedback on it, in case there is an obvious reason in shouldn't work.

\begin{align}
\max & |Y|^2 & \\
\text{subject to:} \\
 Y &= AX \\
 |Y|^2 &< R^2
\end{align}

**UDPATE** 
The optimisation problem as posed won't work... as I'm maximising a convex function instead of a concave....

Comment: So you're trying to solve $AX=R\exp(j\Phi)$? Unless I'm missing something, $X=A^{-1}R\exp(j\Phi)$?

Comment: I don't know what $\Phi$ is..

Comment: So you know $A$ and the magnitude of all of the entries of $Y$ (but not the angle), and you wish to find a real matrix $X$ such that $AX = Y$, correct?

Comment: yes that is correct